# Rigify options/buttons missing from object data properties tab

Tags: armature, rigify

Using rigify I'm trying to make custom rigs / adding to the rigify prebuilds. The problem is that every tutorial I've seen on the subject starts with the rigify buttons option in the armature tab, which is missing for me. When I open the rigify tab all i get is advanced, bone groups, and layer names, no rigify buttons. Where is it or where might a substitute be?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3.2.0, all the Rigify panels have been grouped into one Rigify panel with sub-panels:

[image]

| Blender ≤ 3.1.0 | Blender ≥ 3.2.0 |
| --- | --- |
| Rigify buttons in object (pose) mode | Rigify |
| Rigify buttons in edit mode | Rigify → Samples |
| Rigify Bone Groups | Rigify → Bone Groups |
| Rigify Layer Names | Rigify → Layer Names |
| Rigify (advanced button) | Rigify → Advanced |

Answer (score -1):

Seems like a bug. (Blender 3.6) I pressed generate rig and the samples button showed up under custom properties, far down. Then after deleting it and creating a new bone, the samples showed up as expected.